# Obtaining the largest item in a list using ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am trying to return the largest element in a list `page`:

```
page = [1,2,3];
R.max(page); // returns a function.
R.max(-Infinity, page); // seems correct but doesn't work as expected.
```

Comment: as Javascript is tagged, `Math.min.apply(this,[1,2,3])`

Comment: Note that your title contradicts your question -- do you want the smallest or largest item? I answered for the largest item, getting the smallest one should be easy if you understand the mechanics.

Comment: Yes, as of [0.16](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1277) Ramda's `max` and `min` functions are binary, for reasons described in [Issue 1230](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1230) and implemented in [PR 1231](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1230). The answer from @FrédéricHamidi is probably the simplest way to do this.  Obviously you could create a stand-alone function for this if you need it often.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't have the `ramda` package installed, so this is untested, but from the documentation [max()](http://ramdajs.com/0.16/docs/#max) only takes two arguments, so you would have to [reduce()](http://ramdajs.com/0.16/docs/#reduce) your array upon it:

```
var page = [1, 2, 3],
    result = R.reduce(R.max, -Infinity, page);
// 'result' should be 3.
```

Comment: Tested on ramda's online repl: https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?reduce%28max%2C%20-Infinity%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%29

Answer (score 2):

Use the `apply` function: https://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/#apply

```
const page = [1, 2, 3];
R.apply(Math.max, page); //=> 3
```